# Define certain types in XML Schema, that has to be implemented

Tags: xml, data-structures, xsd

Here is the problem: there is a base schema (game.xsd), that has some "abstract" Type's defined. This schema has to be valid on alone. At the same time, we need to have an opportunity to use this schema (game.xsd) in another, more specific schema (customgame.xsd), where all "abstract" Type's has to be defined.

Basically the idea is **to force** developers of schemas, who use initial schema (game.xsd), **to define** certain Type's.

Variants with xs:redefine / xs:any are already used (problems with different namespaces / too loose definition)

Below are examples of two schemas - initial "base" *game.xsd* and "inherited" *customgame.xsd*.

```
<!-- Omitting definitions for GAME.XSD -->
<xs:schema>
  <xs:element name="BaseGameRule">
    <xs:complexType name="BaseGameRuleType"/>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>

<!-- Omitting definitions for CUSTOMGAME.XSD -->
<xs:schema>
  <!-- How to FORCE use to define BaseGameRuleType ? -->
  <xs:complexType name="BaseGameRuleType"/>
    <xs:sequence>
      <!-- Internal definitions -->
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: @kjhughes I've looked up the examples, still can not find the way to apply "force". Could you please be more specific?

Comment: I'm actually asking you to be more specific and explain what you mean by "force".

Comment: @kjhughes Got it! Under "force" I mean to make a schema developer, who is using my base schema, to define certain types (simple or complex, does not matter). So, basically, base schema (game.xsd) tells us WHAT data structures should exist, and the schemas that use base schema have to DESCRIBE actual structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your right, then you want something like application profiles for your basis schema.

First, a warning.

**Don't do this.**

The idea may be appealing but this is not developer-friendly. What I know very well is an example of [GML](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/gml) which has application profiles. The GML schema is abstract and when you want to apply it to your geographic objects (called *features*), you have to define your own application profile schema. This is what you want with *forcing* developers to implement certain types.

This results in a huge overhead. If you want a certain use case you have to do an application profile schema. XML Schema on itself is not quite easy, the GML schema is hugely complex. Schemas is also a spec level and can be well processed in compile time but not so easy in the runtime. So you force all your use cases to be implemented in the compile time - or be very complex in the implementation.

Now, how to solve it. You can use abstract elements and substitution groups to force developer write application schemas.

Define some abstract base type, say `AbstractGeometryType`.

Define an abstract element of that type:

```
<element name="AbstractGeometry" type="gml:AbstractGeometryType" abstract="true" .../>
```

Use this element in your complex types:

```
<complexType name="GeometryPropertyType">
    <sequence>
        <element ref="gml:AbstractGeometry"/>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

Since this element is abstract, it can't actually appear in an XML instance. So developers will need to define some *concrete* element which would substitute that *abstract* element.

To do this they'll need to create an element which would have a type derived from your abstract base type in the substitution group of your abstract element. For instance:

```
<element name="Point" type="gml:PointType" substitutionGroup="gml:AbstractGeometry"/>
```

Now `Point` may substitute `AbstractGeometry` in your `GeometryPropertyType`.

You can use this trich and define an `AbstractGameRule` element of type `AbstractGameRuleType`. Developers will then need to create `CustomGameRuleType` which would extend `AbstractGameRuleType` and an element `CustomGameRule` which would use `CustomGameRuleType` and habe a substitution group `base:AbstractGameRule`.

But as I said, this is to be used with extreme care.

Answer (score 0):

**You could declare `BaseGameRuleType` to be abstract in game.xsd:**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:complexType name="BaseGameRuleType" abstract="true">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="BaseElement1"/>
      <xs:element name="BaseElement2"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

**And then users could extend `BaseGameRuleType` in their customgame.xsd:**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:include schemaLocation="game.xsd"/>
  <xs:complexType name="GameRuleType">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="BaseGameRuleType">
        <xs:sequence>
          <!-- Define additional elements here -->
          <xs:element name="CustomElement1"/>
          <xs:element name="CustomElement2"/>          
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="BaseGameRule" type="GameRuleType"/>
</xs:schema>
```

**This would allow the following XML to be valid:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BaseGameRule xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="customgame.xsd">
  <BaseElement1/>
  <BaseElement2/>
  <CustomElement1/>
  <CustomElement2/>
</BaseGameRule>
```

If you have extensive requirements on what can and what cannot go into the specific XSD, you might want to consider creating a Schematron-based validator of the specific XSD as that would give you much more flexibility in specifying what is and what is not allowed.